# How to combine first 6 elements using two arrays

Tags: php, arrays, dom

I want to combined first 6 elements from two arrays.

I used following code to combined array.

```
$combined = array_combine($models,$prices);
```

This is the $models array

```
if (!is_null($elements)) {
    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        $nodes = $element->childNodes;
        foreach ($nodes as $node) {

            $modle = $node->nodeValue;
            $modle1 = basename($modle); 
            $models[] = $modle1;

        }
    }
}
```

This is the $prices array

```
if (!is_null($price)) {
  foreach ($price as $p) {

    $nodes1 = $p->childNodes;

    foreach ($nodes1 as $node1) {
      $modlePrice = trim($node1->nodeValue,'Regular Price:');
      $modlePrice1 = basename($modlePrice); 
      $prices[] = $modlePrice1;

    }
  }
}
```

Outputs of these arrays are :-
prices => LKR 295,000.00 LKR 395,000.00 LKR 290,000.00 LKR 150,000.00 LKR 68,000.00 LKR 45,000.00 LKR 31,000.00 LKR 340,000.00

modles => Samsung 40" UA40 ES6220 Series 6 SMART 3D LED TV with 4 glasses
Samsung 55" F8000 Series 8 Smart 3D Full HD LED TV
Samsung 46" F8000 Series 8 Smart 3D Full HD LED TV
Samsung 40" F6400 Series 6 Smart 3D Full HD LED TV etc...

Can anyone help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`array_slice`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) the arrays before combining them.

Answer (score 0):

Try below Code , let me know if any issue ..waiting for your replay...

```
<?php
    // Your Price Result
 $prices = array('LKR 295,000.00','LKR 395,000.00',' LKR 290,000.00',' LKR 150,000.00',' LKR 68,000.00',' LKR 45,000.00',' LKR 31,000.00 ','LKR 340,000.00');
    // Your Modles Results
 $models = array('Samsung 40" UA40 ES6220 Series 6 SMART 3D LED TV with 4 glasses',' Samsung 55" F8000 Series 8 Smart 3D Full HD LED TV ','Samsung 46" F8000 Series 8 Smart 3D Full HD LED TV',' Samsung 40" F6400 Series 6 Smart 3D Full HD LED TV',' Samsung 40" F6400 Series 6 Smart 3D Full HD LED TV' ,' Samsung 48" F6400 Series 4 Smart 3D LED TV' ,' Samsung 48" F6400 Series 6 Smart 2D HD LED TV' ,' Samsung 42" F6400 Series 6 Smart 4D Full HD LED TV'  ); 



 if(sizeof($prices) == sizeof($models)){

 $combined = array_combine($models,$prices);

 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($combined);
 echo "</pre>";
 exit;
 }else{
    echo "Length of array are not same";
 }

?>
```

Comment: Hi Mandip i want to combine until the 7th element

Comment: After combined both array use "array_slice" function Like =====> $oupout=array_slice($combined,0,6); // Total 7 element.....

Comment: Thanks Mandip. first i used array_slice and then combined it. Then it works.

Comment: where are u from @anuruddhika ?